# Python - Iterate through a list, swapping alphbets by indexes?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a code that makes alphabets rotate, through 2 lists.

So I need to define a function, let's say it is called rotate_text.

2 parameters are passed, 1 is string and 1 is integer.

This is my code so far:

```
def rotate_text(text, n):
plaintext = ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
ciphertext = ['FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZABCDE']
rotated_text = []
for i in plaintext:
    rotated_text = ciphertext[plaintext[i + n]]
result = ''.join(rotated_text)
return result
```

So what it needs to do is, if I put ABC for the parameter text and for 2 for the parameter n,

A should return CDE as the result. Or DOG and 11 should return OBK. I don't really think I need that cipertext list so I think I will take that out, but how do I make this code work?

If the program gets ABC as the text, it should find A's index from plaintext list and + n to that index, and find the letter satisfies with plused n index from plaintext list and then.... I am getting a headache.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

How about this code? A `text` should be only capital character.

```
def rotate_text(text, n):
    for i in len(text):
        number = ord(text[i]) - ord('A')
        number = (number + n) % 26
        text[i] = chr(number + ord('A'))
    return text
```

If you want to use lower case too, you should use `if` statements.

Comment: it makes an error at the line number = (number + n) % 26. Invalid syntax it says.